# How can I hide the path from the url in Angular?

Tags: angular, url, path, hide

I am developing an Angular project and I want to hide the path from the URL. I Don't use navigation. That's what I need is when I enter the site just see [www.hgshgs.gr](http://www.hgshgs.gr) and not [www.hgshgs.gr/pages/dashboard](http://www.hgshgs.gr/pages/dashboard). Is there any way to do this?

page-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [{

  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: ECommerceComponent,
      
    },
    {
      path: 'iot-dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent,
      
    },
    
    
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'iot-dashboard',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    
    {
      path: '**',
      component: NotFoundComponent,
    },
  ],

}];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

Comment: You say you don't use navigation but then proceed to show routing definition.

Comment: @MichaelD I mean that I don't have a batton to navigate at an other component.

Comment: You can use component selector in app.compoment.html if you don't want routing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use as following when declaring Router.forRoot

```
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation : false }) ]
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch for youw answer, I have RouterModule.forChild(routes) and I cant add any attributes

Comment: This does not work. I get an error that initialNavigation cannot be assigned a boolean value.